# Divide circle into 3 parts with vertical text inside each sector

Tags: html, css, sass, css-shapes

I need to draw this shape using CSS (without JS or SVG):

[image: 1]

with these conditions:

- Text should be in one position - absolutely vertically.
- It something like a circle divided into 3 parts without an outer border.
- Center should be empty (optional).

What I tried: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0jmv9sbr/2/). But it rotates text.
Also, I tried to use `rotate` with `translateY` property but it compresses the text:

[image: Bottom number]

Comment: what does 'Text should be in one position - absolutely vertically.' mean?

Comment: @AHaworth, sorry for confusion, I mean that the text should always be in a vertical position, not rotated towards the center (as on my fiddle).

Comment: Use an SVG, much simpler

Comment: @Paulie_D, there can be many such shapes and the text in each of them will be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing the borders and rotations on :after pseudo-elements instead of the li's

you can translate to get the empty center.

and then just position the text
like this:

```css
.circle {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}


li:after {
  content:"";
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20%;
  right: -20%;
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
  border-bottom: solid black 1px;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-left: -5px;
}

li:first-child:after {
  transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(30deg) translate(5px);
}

li:first-child .text {
  top: 25%;
  left: 75%;
}

li:nth-child(2):after {
  transform: rotate(120deg) skewY(30deg) translate(5px);
}

li:nth-child(2) .text {
  top: 70%;
  left: 50%;
}

li:nth-child(3):after {
  transform: rotate(240deg) skewY(30deg) translate(5px);
}

li:nth-child(3) .text {
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="circle">
  <li>
    <div class="text">1</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="text">2</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="text">3</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```